# Identity Involving Laplace Transform And Its Inverse

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

A simple question.

Suppose that a function $f$ is $L^1_\text{loc}([0,\infty[)$ and of exponential order.
Then the Laplace transform of $f$ always exists because its satisfies a notorious sufficient condition for the existence of Laplace Transform.
For this type of function, is the following identity always valid?
$$f(s)=\mathcal{L}\{ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{f\}\}=\int^\infty_0 e^{-st} \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{f(s)\}(t) \, dt $$ 
In other words, if I know that a function $f$ admits Laplace Transform, can I always express $f$ as the Laplace Transform of its Inverse Laplace Transform or I need further conditions?

Thanks